# Text data Convert to CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a text file and i want to convert it to csv file. 
text file data is as below.

```
 Backed Up         Expires       Files       KB  C  Sched Type   Policy
    ----------------  ---------- -------- --------  -  ------------ ------------
    08/14/2015 08:12  INFINITY      24270  5790924  N  Full Backup  WIN_DEFAULT
    08/14/2015 08:01  INFINITY         14   180963  N  Full Backup  WIN_DEFAULT
    08/14/2015 18:00  INFINITY         13  1378724  N  Full Backup  WIN_DEFAULT
    08/11/2015 09:45  INFINITY      15500 22320247  N  Full Backup  WIN_DEFAULT
    08/11/2015 09:27  INFINITY     108540 23920970  N  Full Backup  WIN_DEFAULT
    08/11/2015 09:27  08/02/2016       15  1470559  N  Full Backup  WIN_DEFAULT
```

I tried to below script but it is showing in single column in csv file.

```
import-csv ANP.TXT -delimiter "`t" | export-csv ANP1.csv
```

I tried `Get-content` and `Convertto-CSV` as well but output is coming in Single column.

Please advise me how to convert it csv.

Comment: I think the problem is that your file is not tab-delimited, I tried the same command with your sample data and got the same result as you, then edited the file replacing spacing with tabs and that way it works.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But is there anyway i can do by script to convert it to csv. I don't want to perform the same activity manually on multiple files.

Comment: If it's not actually tab delimited data, you'd likely have to read each line, and then get each fields value as a substring of the line, which shouldn't be too tough because the data looks like it must use fixed width columns?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make it tab-delimited:

```
 Get-Content ANP.txt | ForEach-Object { $_.trimStart().trimEnd() -replace '  +',"`t"} > ANP2.txt
```

Then convert to CSV:

```
import-csv ANP2.TXT -delimiter "`t" | export-csv ANP.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try.